# While calling bank api :The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, .net

i'm trying to get the access bank api using Below code to call bank API 
    with parameter and also authenticate url with username password 
    When call bank API showing Unauthorized API but here i added certificate 
    and also set cros-option but still error is coming..

```
Anyone can help me....

:
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testclient", "test@123");
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;    //  request.ContentType = "application/json";    //request.ContentType = "";
            using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            long length = 0;
            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    length = response.ContentLength;
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) throw new Exception(String.Format(
                        "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode,
                    response.StatusDescription));
                    Stream stream1 = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
                    string strsb = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    object objResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strsb);
                    //return objResponse;
                }

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Log exception
            }

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Comment: certificate with pass, client id and secret in header

X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2("D:\\demo\\temp.crt", "temp", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("temp", "temp");
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Basic dGVzdGNsaWVudDp0ZXN0QDEyMw==");
            request.Headers.Add("X-IBM-Client-Id", "id");
            request.Headers.Add("X-IBM-Client-Secret", "secret");

Answer (score 0):

> Add certificate with pass, client id and secret in header

**X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2("D:\demo\temp.crt", "temp", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet); request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert); request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"; request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("temp", "temp"); request.Headers.Add("authorization", "authorization"); request.Headers.Add("X-IBM-Client-Id", "id"); request.Headers.Add("X-IBM-Client-Secret", "secret");**